Connecting Excel to Fabric
Is it possible to connect Excel to the Data Warehouse or Lakehouse within Microsoft Fabric ? Like using get data or something like that ?

Yes it is possible, using the Data Warehouse, or the Data lake SQL Endpoint. It is just a SQL Connection.
In this example I've used the default SQL endpoint created when you create a Lake House.
In Fabric, go to the Lake House and click the 'Settings' icon

Then the 'About' Section, copy the SQL Connection String

You can then use, Excel's (Or Power BI) Get Data feature. Select 'From SQL Server Database'

Copy connection string into the Server, and then go through the login process for your account:

It will now allow you to connect to the Database objects


You can add file to lakehouse's Files folder using "Upload" option:

From there you can use a notebook, for example, to perform transformations and save to a Lakehouse as a table.
Another way is to use a Dataflow Gen2 using the Excel connector to load, transform and save to a Lakehouse as a table.

Hi, I want to see if the other way around is possible, can I use Excel's Get Data feature or something to connect to the lakehouse ?

so you want to pull data from a fabric lakehouse and analyse it in excel?

Yes Andrii exactly
